# node.js localhost loads and loads but doesnt work

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch

I am trying to call a search engine from this node API but for some reason node doesn't work when I put "/search" into the url. I tried the client.search call without the API and it works. Thank you for any input!

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const PORT = 4000;
var client = require ('./connection.js');
var argv = require('yargs').argv;
var getJSON = require('get-json');

let app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ exptended: true }));

app.get("/search", function results(request, response) {
  client.search({
    index: 'club',
    type: 'clubinfo',
    body: {
      query: {
        match: { "name": "Italian club" }
      },
    }
  },function (error, response,status) {
      if (error){
        console.log("search error: "+error)
      }
      else {
        console.log("--- Response ---");
        console.log(response);
        console.log("--- Hits ---");
        response.hits.hits.forEach(function(hit){
          console.log(hit);
        })
      }
  });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log('wowzers in me trousers, Listening on port ' + PORT));
```

Comment: You need to send a response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You're overriding the `response` variable. Use different names for the *Express* response and the response sent back from your `client.search`
- You actually need to send back the *response*. To do that call `response.send({ // somethingHere })`.

In your case, it might look like this

```
app.get("/search", function (request, response) {
  client.search({
    index: 'club',
    type: 'clubinfo',
    body: {
      query: {
        match: { "name": "Italian club" }
      },
    }
  },function (error, data, status) {
      if (error){
        console.log("search error: "+error);

        // Send back an error resposne
        response.status(500).send(error);
      }
      else {
        console.log("--- Response ---");
        console.log(data);
        console.log("--- Hits ---");
        data.hits.hits.forEach(function(hit){
          console.log(hit);
        })

        // Send back the response
        response.send(data);
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank man, I think that helped. I am not getting an error lessage in my console:  TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Comment: is the browser still loading indefinitely?

Comment: yeah for a while with no outcome

Comment: Update: its working! I deleted the console.log and now it works.